# Jquery Draggable On Map bounces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I am trying to use the JQuery Dragable.  My theory is that I will have a map and I will append Div's being images to this map.  Now I can do this no problem using Jquery and they move around fine.  The problem is when I press remove on the earliest div added it moves the other div's around including their positions.

I include HTML Code. http://jsfiddle.net/7XCHQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use position absolute to achieve this like the example here http://jsfiddle.net/7XCHQ/4/

```
.cameraDiv
{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```